# Webpack browsersync/html-load?

Tags: webpack

Webpack won't load `index.html` in browser,  loads listing directory. 
Does anybody have any idea if I am structuring it wrong? 
https://github.com/ioanachi/WebpackBase

Comment: please, feel free to pull down the repository and check it out,

Comment: Please add your webpack config to the question (links could not exist in future)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. The  problem was the browsersync version. Works fine with   "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",